# How to set RealmDefaultConfiguration with encryption key

Tags: android, realm

I am using realm database in my app, and currently in the `Application` class I am initialising realm with default configuration and everywhere in the app I am using `Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()` to query/save data.

Now I wanted to encrypt the database and I did as following

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .encryptionKey(getKeyFunction())
            .migration(new MyMigration())
            .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);`
```

But when I try to access `Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()` I get `Invalid format of Realm File` error.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to use the same key for decryption as you do for encryption: meaning you must remember the key you use to first create the encrypted Realm file

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code. I have tested this in my sample project

```
    // Generate a key
    // IMPORTANT! This is a silly way to generate a key. It is also never stored.
    // For proper key handling please consult:
    // * https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html
    // * http://nelenkov.blogspot.dk/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html
    Realm.init(this);
    byte[] key = new byte[64];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(key);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .encryptionKey(key)
            .build();

    // Start with a clean slate every time
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    // Open the Realm with encryption enabled
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    //realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    // Everything continues to work as normal except for that the file is encrypted on disk
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Person person = realm.createObject(Person.class);
            person.setName("Happy Person");
            person.setAge(14);
        }
    });

    Person person = realm.where(Person.class).findFirst();
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Person name: %s", person.getName()));
```

Comment: My concern was how can I set this as default configuration and access Realm instance with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` Doing this I need to give the encryption key once while configuring.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please have a look into that.